# do while loop with try catch

Tags: java, try-catch, do-while

What is wrong with my code? I'm trying request prompt a user to enter a number if it is not between 1 and 6 or a number it should say invalid and prompt another try. The user may only have 3 tries.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[6];

    System.out.println("Enter a number on a die from 1-6:");
    String dieinput = input.next();
    int invalidcount = 0;
    System.out.println("Your number is: " + dieinput);



    do{
    try
    {
      // the String to int conversion
      int dienum = Integer.parseInt(dieinput.trim());
      int dienumOE = 0;
      int count=0;

      //test number input
      if ((dienum >= 1) && (dienum<= 6))
            System.out.println("number is " + dienum + oddoreven(dienum));
      else
            System.out.println("Invalid number, please enter a number 1-6");
            count++;
            System.out.println("Count" + count);
      }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("Invalid number, please enter a number 1-6");
        System.out.println("Count" + count);
        }
    while (count <= 3 && count >=0);
    }
    }





// Check if odd or even
public static String oddoreven(int num) {
    String result;

    if (num % 2 == 0)
        result = "even";
    else
        result = "odd";
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop. You're setting count to 0 at the start of each loop.  See the answer below, but don't set this variable to zero inside the loop either.

Comment: Please post a complete example - your source code doesn't even compile.

Comment: I changed the int counter but the do-while is still on working correct. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is "wrong" scoping: You can't use a variable within the **catch** block that is declared within the scope of the **try** block!

In other words; you need:

```
int counter = 0;
try { ...
} catch (...
```

if you want to use counter within **both** try and **catch**!

The "rule" is very simple: a variable is only visible up to that } that closes the "block" it is in.

That prevents you from actually compiling your code!

So, the **real** lesson here is more like: do not write 100 lines of code to *then* run the compiler. Only write as few lines as possible - every time when you think: this is "enough" to compile .. then **compile**. And then fix the errors reported to you. The java compiler is really good at giving you specific messages that tell you what you did wrong; but the **more** messy code you put up, the harder that gets!

And for the record: SO is not a "remote" compiler service that you should use to get your messy code to compile!

Comment: *And for the record: SO is not a "remote" compiler service that you should use to get your messy code to compile!* which is funny, because you did just that. There are duplicates of those questions, there is no need to answer again.